# Improving SQL Query Select Performance

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have a SQL query that pulls data from multiple tables. The only issue I am having is really the query takes to long and I was wondering if there is anyway I can speed it up. I made some minor improvements by using INNER JOIN rather than LEFT JOIN but the query is to slow.

```
SELECT 
    clientlist.CRMContactId,
    clientlist.ClientAdviser,
    COALESCE(NULLIF(clientlist.FirstName, ""), clientlist.CorporateName) AS FirstName,
    clientlist.LastName,
    clientlist.ServiceStatusName, 
    FORMAT(t.totalfum, 2) AS "Funds Under Management",
    FORMAT(d.totalfci, 2) AS "Total Income", 
    (SELECT DueDate 
     FROM tasks 
     WHERE ClientRef = clientlist.ClientRef 
       AND `Status` <> "Complete" 
     ORDER BY DueDate DESC 
     LIMIT 1) AS NextDate, 
    (SELECT CompletedDate 
     FROM tasks 
     WHERE ClientRef = clientlist.ClientRef 
       AND `Status` = "Complete" 
     ORDER BY DueDate DESC 
     LIMIT 1) AS LastDate 
FROM 
    clientlist
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         plans.ClientId, SUM(plans.CurrentVal) AS totalfum
     FROM 
         plans
     GROUP BY 
         plans.ClientId) t ON clientlist.CRMContactId = t.ClientId
INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
         adviserfci.ClientId, SUM(adviserfci.Payable) AS totalfci
     FROM 
         adviserfci
     WHERE 
         IncomeType IN ("Renewal Commission", "Ongoing Fee", "Fund Based Commission") 
         OR (Incometype = "Payaway Received" 
             AND UnderlyingIncomeType IN ("Renewal", "Ongoing Fee", "Fund Based"))
     GROUP BY 
         adviserfci.ClientId) d ON clientlist.CRMContactId = d.ClientId
WHERE 
    d.totalfci IS NOT NULL
```

I've also read somewhere the explain command will help determine issues however I don't understand the response.

[image]

Is there any way I can increase the performance of this query?

Comment: Which variety of SQL software are you targeting?

Comment: If you take a look at your `execution plan` that will show you which parts are slow.  Without access to the data it's a lot of guessing on our part.  You can also just toss the whole thing into `Engine Tuning Advisor` and see what SQL thinks (if this is MSSQL).

Comment: Also, how long does it take to run and how many rows are returned? In my experience, using OR can really slow things down; it's often better performance to run two separate queries union'd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fold the test for `d.totalfci IS NOT NULL` into the subquery that generates it, even if it needs to be in a `HAVING` clause.

Add some indexes

```
tasks:  INDEX(ClientRef, `Status`, DueDate)
plans:  INDEX(ClientId, CurrentVal)
adviserfci:  INDEX(ClientId)
```

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost do you have indexes created for these tables?

Without knowing your data structured and what kind of query load you're going to be putting in them is hard to tell but on first look I'd say these indexes should improve performance, if you don't have them yet:

- CRMContactId on table clientlist
- ClientId on table plans
- ClientId on adviserfci (include IncomeType and Payable)

If you haven't set up table primary keys yet and from the column names they sound like decent candidate keys, so if that works you can kill two birds with one stone.